# Windows lists the wrong Directshow Audio Capture Devices

Tags: windows-7, audio, directshow

Some time ago the directshow audio capture devices on my Win7 machine stopped updating.

For example
`ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy`
lists devices that have been uninstalled already and my microphone won't appear after connecting it.

I think the problem started after installing a Microsoft Windows Platform update but uninstalling it didn't solve the problem.

I can manually add my microphone through the registry and make it accessible in tools such Wirecast and FFMPEG:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\ActiveMovie\devenum\{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\Mikrofon (IDT High Definition A]
"FriendlyName"="Mikrofon (IDT High Definition A"
"CLSID"="{E30629D2-27E5-11CE-875D-00608CB78066}"
"FilterData"=hex:02,00,00,00,00,00,20,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"WaveInId"=dword:00000002
```

I've extracted this key from a working Windows VHD instance running on the same machine.

Anyone knows how to make Windows make recognize again the correct audio devices?

Thanks